The problem of "The application contains no execute() calls" in Flink
Why Does "org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: The application contains no execute() calls" Occur When I Change the Processing Function of a Flink Task from KeyedProcessFunction to KeyedCoProcessFunction?
The error log is as follows:
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: The application contains no execute() calls.  
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:957) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:940) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.runApplicationEntryPoint(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:385) \~\[flink-dist-1.17.1-h3.xxx.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.lambda$runApplicationAsync$3(ApplicationDispatcherBootstrap.java:303) \~\[flink-dist-1.17.1-h3.xxx.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) \~\[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ActorSystemScheduledExecutorAdapter.java:171) \~\[flink-rpc-akka_9c16cc6a-e7af-4810-9573-6a1dc248ae52.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:68) \~\[flink-rpc-akka_9c16cc6a-e7af-4810-9573-6a1dc248ae52.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.lambda$withContextClassLoader$0(ClassLoadingUtils.java:41) \~\[flink-rpc-akka_9c16cc6a-e7af-4810-9573-6a1dc248ae52.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:49) \[flink-rpc-akka_9c16cc6a-e7af-4810-9573-6a1dc248ae52.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:48) \[flink-rpc-akka_9c16cc6a-e7af-4810-9573-6a1dc248ae52.jar:1.17.1-h3.xxx\]  
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289) \[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056) \[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692) \[?:1.8.0_402\]  
at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:175) \[?:1.8.0_402\]  
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.deployment.application.ApplicationExecutionException: The application contains no execute() calls.  
... 13 more

I've brought in another stream and connected the two streams together. The strange problem looks like it's caused by API incompatibility.
I don‘t know how to deal with this problem, i do nothing.
How can I solve this problem? Thank you for your help.

The API doesn't allow you to just replace a KeyedProcessFunction with a KeyedCoProcessFunction -- you have to introduce another stream, and connect the two streams. If you could kindly provide enough context so that someone could reproduce the problem you've encountered, then perhaps someone can diagnose the problem.
